# Android app show data on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android

Some mobile devices show data like Sony Xperia Acro S, zenfone, China's Band while some other device does not show data like samsung, Sony Xperia M5. I don't know what the problem is. Please Help Me, Thank you all in advance. Here is the code:

```
public class ActivityForm5 extends Activity {

//ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form5);


    final String NAMESPACE = "http://webapp.ombudsman.go.th/Mobile_WService";
    final String URL = "http://webapp.ombudsman.go.th/mobile_wservice/service.asmx";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://webapp.ombudsman.go.th/Mobile_WService/ComplainDetail";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "ComplainDetail";


    final String CpID = getIntent().getStringExtra("cp_id");

    SoapObject table = null;                                // Contains table of dataset that returned through SoapObject
    SoapObject client = null;                               // Its the client petition to the web service
    SoapObject tableRow = null;                             // Contains row of table
    SoapObject responseBody = null;                         // Contains XML content of dataset
    HttpTransportSE transport = null;                       // That call webservice
    SoapSerializationEnvelope sse = null;

    sse = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    ////sse.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "movie", this.getClass());
    sse.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ActivityForm5", this.getClass());    //Note if class name isn't "movie" ,you must change 
    sse.dotNet = true;                                                  // if WebService written .Net is result=true
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    //movie setmovie = new movie();
    try 
    {
        client = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        client.addProperty("p_cp_id", CpID);
        sse.setOutputSoapObject(client);
        sse.bodyOut = client;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, sse);

        // This step: get file XML
        responseBody = (SoapObject) sse.getResponse();
        // remove information XML,only retrieved results that returned
        responseBody = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(1);
        // get information XMl of tables that is returned
        table = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(0);

        //Get information each row in table,0 is first row
        tableRow = (SoapObject) table.getProperty(0);

        TextView txtRunningNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RunningNo);
        txtRunningNo.setText(tableRow.getProperty("RUNNING_NO").toString());
        TextView txtChannal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Channal);
        txtChannal.setText(tableRow.getProperty("CHANNEL_NAME").toString());
        TextView txtDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Date);
        txtDate.setText(tableRow.getProperty("RUNNING_DATE").toString());
        TextView txtDep = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dep);
        txtDep.setText(tableRow.getProperty("RESPONSE_GROUP").toString());
        TextView txtAgent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Agent);
        txtAgent.setText(tableRow.getProperty("RESPONSE_NAME").toString());
        TextView txtPresentDo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PresentDo);
        txtPresentDo.setText(tableRow.getProperty("PROCESS_NAME").toString());

        TextView txtStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Status);
        txtStatus.setText(tableRow.getProperty("END_STATUS").toString());

        TextView txtPerson= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Person);
        txtPerson.setText(tableRow.getProperty("NAME").toString());

        TextView txtOgn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ogn);
        txtOgn.setText(tableRow.getProperty("ORG_NAME").toString());

        TextView txtType= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Type);
        txtType.setText(tableRow.getProperty("ATTRIBUTE_NAME").toString());
        TextView txtIssue= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Issue);
        txtIssue.setText(tableRow.getProperty("Issue_Detail").toString());
        TextView txtProblem= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Problem);
        txtProblem.setText(tableRow.getProperty("subIssue_Detail").toString());

        Button buttonStep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Step);
        buttonStep.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Toast.makeText(ActivityForm5.this,
                        String.valueOf("CP_ID : " + CpID.toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this,ActivityForm7.class);
                            newActivity.putExtra("cp_id", CpID);
                            newActivity.putExtra("btn", "Step");
                            String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
                            String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                            newActivity.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);
                            newActivity.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });
        Button buttonCp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Cp);
        buttonCp.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Toast.makeText(ActivityForm5.this,
                        String.valueOf("CP_ID : " + CpID.toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this,ActivityForm6.class);
                            newActivity.putExtra("cp_id", CpID);
                            newActivity.putExtra("btn", "Detail");
                            String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
                            String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                            newActivity.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);
                            newActivity.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });            
        Button buttonIss = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Issue);
        buttonIss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Toast.makeText(ActivityForm5.this,
                        String.valueOf("CP_ID : " + CpID.toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this,ActivityForm6.class);
                            newActivity.putExtra("cp_id", CpID);
                            newActivity.putExtra("btn", "Issue");
                            String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
                            String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                            newActivity.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);
                            newActivity.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });
        Button buttonFact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Fact);
        buttonFact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Toast.makeText(ActivityForm5.this,
                        String.valueOf("CP_ID : " + CpID.toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this,ActivityForm6.class);
                            newActivity.putExtra("cp_id", CpID);
                            newActivity.putExtra("btn", "Fact");
                            String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
                            String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                            newActivity.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);
                            newActivity.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });
        Button buttonJudge= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Judge);
        buttonJudge.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Toast.makeText(ActivityForm5.this,
                        String.valueOf("CP_ID : " + CpID.toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this,ActivityForm6.class);
                            newActivity.putExtra("cp_id", CpID);
                            newActivity.putExtra("btn", "Judge");
                            String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
                            String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                            newActivity.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);
                            newActivity.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });



    }catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }                          
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test, menu);
    return true;
}   

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_complain:   
       Intent i = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this, ActivityForm2.class);

       String permissionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("permission_Code");
       if (permissionCode.matches("0"))
            {
                String sectionCode = "";
                i.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
            }
            else
            {
                String sectionCode = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_Code");
                i.putExtra("section_Code", sectionCode);
            }    
       String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_Id");
       i.putExtra("permission_Code", permissionCode);

       i.putExtra("user_Id", userId);

       startActivity(i);
       return true;

    case R.id.menu_search:
        //System.out.println("ADD SYMBOL CLICKED!");
        /*Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, ActivityFormSearch.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
        return true;*/
        Intent i2 = new Intent(ActivityForm5.this, ActivityFormSearch.class);
        startActivity(i2);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug ?What's the error?

Comment: i not met error. i can send my project if you want

Comment: i run on AVD .not show data too and log cat show W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6934360, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Just try to debug.Then you would be able to undestand where it get stuck.

Comment: on Genymotion at line : 
table = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(0);

have get value but on AVD not get value.

Comment: i think this is problem

responseBody = (SoapObject) sse.getResponse();
responseBody = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(1);

it get value not true on AVD. But on Genymotion value is true